# Recursive query

Tags: postgis, postgresql

How can I do a recursive query with these 2 queries:

```
SELECT
ptb.* AS pois
FROM ways way, pois pta, pois ptb
WHERE way.id = 1
  AND pta.id = 12
  AND ST_DWithin(
  ST_LineSubstring(
  way.path,
  ST_LineLocatePoint(way.path, pta.lonlat::geometry) + 20000 / ST_Length(way.path, false),
  ST_LineLocatePoint(way.path, pta.lonlat::geometry) + 40000 / ST_Length(way.path, false)
  )::geography,
  ptb.lonlat::geography,
  4000)
```

[image: Query 1]

This first query is for find all POIs around a track (between 2 others POIs). I get a list of green POIs and return A & B.

I need to find the distance from a POI, from each POIs from the list.
For that, I have write a second query :

```
      SELECT
    ST_Distance(way.path::geography, pta.lonlat::geography) +
    ST_Distance(way.path::geography, ptb.lonlat::geography) +
    ST_Length(ST_LineSubstring(
      way.path,
      least(ST_LineLocatePoint(way.path, pta.lonlat::geometry), ST_LineLocatePoint(way.path, ptb.lonlat::geometry)),
      greatest(ST_LineLocatePoint(way.path, pta.lonlat::geometry), ST_LineLocatePoint(way.path, ptb.lonlat::geometry))),false)  AS dst_line
   FROM ways way, pois pta, pois ptb
   WHERE way.id = 1
     AND pta.id = 12
     AND ptb.id = #{poi2.id}
```

[image: Query 2]

This query return the distance between pta to ptb (A & B) - Not by fly, but along the linestring

pta => ptb(A) = 25 km

pta => ptb(B) = 35 km

How can I do a recursive query ? Is it a good idea

Comment: I doubt it; truly [recursive queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-SELECT) are a good idea *if* explicitly needed, but I have the feeling you are rather looking for [iteration](https://medium.com/kkempin/postgresqls-lateral-join-bfd6bd0199df) here? it also sounds like you want to perform a *(K) Nearest Neighbor* search? ...could you maybe add a picture describing your intentions?

Comment: Recursive queries are generally best for things that involve tree or graph like search. It is a little bit hard to understand what your 2nd query is doing, but there doesn't appear to be anything recursive about it. In my experience, they are very slow and to be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @ThingumaBob. Funnily enough, recursive queries are in fact iterative -- it is a complete misnomer, as [the note in the docs states](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html). :D

Comment: @JohnPowell :D ah man, might I actually have been failing recursively in terminology here? ...should indeed have taken care to be more explicit.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I updated my question and added images. ;)